# Эффективное сопоставление динамических ключей

Tags: javascript, node.js, map, производительность

Мне надо наиболее эффективно (быстро) сопоставлять ключи со значениями, вот пример со статическими ключами:

```
const routes = new Map([
  ["/test0", () => console.log("passed 0")],
  ["/test1", () => console.log("passed 1")],
  ["/test2", () => console.log("passed 2")],
]);

const getRoute = (path) => {
  if (routes.has(path)) {
    routes.get(path)();
  } else {
    console.error("404");
  }
};

getRoute("/test0");
```

Как мне сделать динамические, вида `/test/:one/:two/passed`, где `:one` и `:two` могут быть любыми строками? Как эффективнее это реализовать **БЕЗ ЦИКЛОВ И REGEXP** в getRoute?

Comment: Я не бэк, но тут всё должно быть просто)) Я не очень понял, что именно не получается с `new Map()`. Вы просто объявляете заранее все нужные ключ-значения, потом получаете значение `getRoute(one)` и смотрите равен ли он `two`. Я просто не знаю как там строчки приходят, но если вам регистр букв мешает и вы хотите без `regexp`, то можете привести строчки в нижний регистр и так сравнивать

Comment: Тут так не получится: one и two - это переменные, мы не можем знать заранее их значение, они могут представлять из себя любую строку, например /test/:one/:two/passed - это /test/foo/bar/passed. В конечном итоге они должны передаваться в эндпонит в виде объекта: { one: "foo", two: "bar" }.

Comment: То что они переменные никак не мешает, тому алгоритму что я описал. Если вам просто надо отправить объект, то можете отправить как `{one, two}` и он автоматически создаст объект с ключами `one` и `two` и со значениями переменных `one` и `two`

Comment: Попробую описать по другому и с самого начала: на бэке создается роутер, представляющий собой http сервер, в который попадают запросы. Каждый запрос имеет метод и url. Еще до запуска сервера мы должны построить статический список ассоциаций url+method с функциями-эндпоинтами или массивами middleware. Когда сервер запустится и в него придет запрос, то мы должны понять, какой экнпоинт отдать по этому url и методу. Иногда бывает ситуация, когда url не статический, то есть url не соответствует ключу в Map. Задача в том, чтобы найти наиболее эффективный способ это делать.

Answer (score 0):

Совсем без циклов вы никак не обойдётесь, но есть способ сократить количество итераций, применимый когда длина маршрутов заметно меньше их количества.

Для этого побьём все конечные точки на сегменты, и построим из них дерево следующей структуры (я использую typescript для описания интерфейсов):

```typescript
type RouteNode = {
    routes: { [key: string]: RouteNode | undefined },
    default?: RouteNode,
    final?: { handler: Function, variableNames: string[] },
}
```

Здесь свойство routes отвечает за статические маршруты, вроде ваших test0-test2; свойство default отвечает за маршрут с переменной; ну а final отвечает за маршрут, который заканчивается на текущем элементе; handler - это обработчик маршрута, ну а variables - имена переменных (one, two), если они вам нужны.

Составить литерал подобного дерева маршрутов можно и вручную, но лучше поручить его составление компьютеру (в комментариях я пишу typescript-описания типов):

```js
function emptyNode() /*: RouteNode*/ {
    return {
        routes: Object.create(null)
    }
}

function addRoute(root/*: RouteNode*/, path/*: string*/, handler/*: Function*/) {
    let node = root;
    let variableNames = [];
    for (const segment of path.split('/')) {
        if (!segment.startsWith(':')) {
            // Обычный сегмент маршрута
            node = node.routes.next ??= emptyNode();
        } else {
            // Сегмент-переменная
            node = node.default ??= emptyNode();
            variableNames.push(segment.substr(1));
        }
    }

    if (node.final)
        throw new Error("Маршрут уже существует");

    node.final = { handler, variableNames };
}
```

Здесь я использую `Object.create(null)`, чтобы среди ключей не затесались такие методы как `toString` и пр.

Теперь, когда дерево построено, можно искать в нём совпадения:

```js
function getRoute(root/*: RouteNode*/, path/*: string*/) {
    let node = root;
    let variableValues = [];
    for (const segment of path.split('/')) {
        const next = node.routes[segment];
        if (next) {
            // Обычный сегмент
            node = next;
        } else if (node.default) {
            // Сегмент-переменная
            node = node.default;
            variableValues.push(segment);
        } else {
            // Маршрут не найден
            return null;
        }
    }

    if (!node.final) {
        // Маршрут всё ещё не найден
        return null;
    }

    let variablesObj = Object.create(null);
    for (let i=0; i<node.final.variables.length; i++) {
        variablesObj[node.final.variableNames[i]] = variableValues[i];
    }

    return {
        handler: node.final.handler,
        variables: variableValuesObj,
    }
}
```

Comment: При таком подходе можно завести маршруты `/users/me` и `/users/:id` одновременно?

Comment: @ЕгорБанин да, можно. У первого будет приоритет.

Comment: Для сегмента надо будет запустить цикл сопоставления с образцом? Если маршруты будут немного сложнее, типа `/user-:id`, то сегмент придётся тоже парсить. Тогда ваш поход по графу начнёт превращаться в реализацию regexp: сопоставляем сегменты символ за символом, в случае неудачи переходим к следующей альтернативе и повторяем. Я не против вашего решения, но хотел отметить, что самописное сопоставление или регулярки принципиально не отличаются.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин да, вы правы, для более сложных маршрутов будет более сложное дерево. Но нет, отличие от регулярок тут принципиальное: регулярки вы в цикле проверяете все, за время O(N), где N - количество маршрутов. А тут цикл идёт по глубине маршрута.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин эквивалент на регулярках вы сможете получить если объедините все маршруты через | и прогоните одну регулярку, компилированную в DFA. К сожалению, стандартная библиотека javascript не поддерживает DFA на основных платформах.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин если интересно направление с регулярками - надо брать библиотеку вроде вот этой: https://npm.io/package/regex-to-dfa

Answer (score -2):

Во-первых, регекспы очень быстры и эффективны. Вы можете переписать их заново на js, но быстрее точно не получится.

Во-вторых, оптимизация может заключаться в кэшировании вашей динамики в мап. То есть, кто-то завёл очень популярный роут /test/iLove/regexp/passed, вы его один раз сматчили с эндпоинтом и записали этот матч в мап. А потом миллионы пользователей получили этот эндпоинт за константное время.

Если вы всё-таки решитесь писать свой регексп, то без циклов (рекурсии) вам не обойтись. Вам надо будет парсить path буква за буквой. Даже если у вас будут очень простые правила, то это будет медленнее аналогичного регекспа (node против c++).

```
^test\/(?<one>[^\/]+)\/(?<two>[^\/]+)\/passed$
```

---

Когда-то и меня вела дорога приключений... Я реализовывал с другом наперегонки очень быстрый роутинг. Мы шли ноздря в ноздрю, боролись за каждый тик. А потом мы сравнили наши поделки с регекспом. Регексп оказался быстрее в тысячи раз.

---

UPD: пример кода с циклом и регулярками (потом сравните это со своим решением без регулярок)

```js
let routes = {
  '^get \/$': () => 'main',
  '^(?<method>[a-z]+) \/(?<service>[^\/]+)$': g => `${g.service}.${g.method}`,
  '^(?<method>[a-z]+) \/(?<service>[^\/]+)\/(?<id>[^\/]+)$': g => `${g.service}.${g.method}.id`,
};

let services = {
  'main': () => console.log('main'),
  'articles.get': () => console.log('articles index'),
  'articles.get.id': g => console.log('get article #' + g.id),
  'comments.post': () => console.log('add comment'),
  // +100500 разных эндпоинтов
};

function route(services, routes, url) {
  for (let pattern in routes) {
    let r = RegExp(pattern);
    let matches = r.exec(url.toLowerCase());
    if (matches !== null) {
      let service = services[routes[pattern](matches.groups)];
      if (service !== undefined) {
        return service(matches.groups);
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log('404');
}

route(services, routes, 'GET /');
route(services, routes, 'GET /articles');
route(services, routes, 'GET /articles/123');
route(services, routes, 'POST /comments');
route(services, routes, 'GET /foo/bar');
```

Если url'ы шаблонные, то регулярок получается немного, а дальше быстрый мап по уникальному идентификатору эндпоинта.

Comment: А можете рассказать по подробнее, как бы Вы конкретно реализовали сопоставления url с регулярками? Мне на ум не пришло ничего лучше, чем генерить регулярки на этапе добавления роута, а затем при сопоставлении перебирать их. Проблема производительности этого варианта, на мой взгляд, как раз в переборе. Пример добавил в вопрос (второй вариант).

Comment: @posix если маршруты динамические, то по идее должно хватать десятка другого маршрутов. Для всякого REST'а обычно хватает нескольких, типа: `:метод /:имя_ресурса`, `:метод /:имя_ресурса/:id`. Всякие фильтры летают в query-параметрах, данные -- в теле запроса. Естественно, регулярки не должны быть сложными.

Comment: @posix кажется понял ваше затруднение. Смотрите, мапа по эднпоинтам остаётся. Там что-то типа `'articles.get.id': id => console.log('articles get ' + id)` а роут такой `'^(?<method>[a-z]+) \/(?<service>[^\/]+)\/(?<id>[^\/]+)$': '{service}.{method}.id'`. Роут сроутит и правильные урлы и те, которые не соответствуют ни одному эндпоинту. Если в мапе эндпоинтов ничего подходящего нет, то 404.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин смотрю я ваш код и вижу строчку `let r = RegExp(pattern);`. Если вы хотите чтобы ваши регулярки и правда были быстрыми - её надо выносить на этап инициализации, нельзя такое делать при каждом поиске! Ну и не забывайте про new.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Всё так и url лучше ловеркейсить не в цикле и тд. Но это же просто быстренько состряпанный пример, выражение идеи, что регулярка пишется не на каждый из существующих урлов, а на пачки, а потом уже выбирается подходящий обработчик из мапы.